# What is SQL Server Profile aside from SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

"As a requirement, the Analytical Accounting user's SQL Server profile must be part of the DYNGRP SQL Server group in order to run FRx successfully."

I'm just curious about this SQL Server Profile, is this another tool from SQL Server or a term use for an account credentials for the user using SQL Server.

Thanks in advance. Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are talking about the user(s) that connect to SQL Server.